# Download any content type using Struts2

Tags: struts2

```
<action name="downloadFiles" method="downloadFiles" class="org.filemanager.action.SystemAction">
    <result name="success" type="stream">
        <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
        <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
        <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${folderOrFileName}"</param>
        <param name="bufferSize">200000</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

As code shown above:
How can I set the content type, so that any content type can be downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please visit [this link](http://webdesign.about.com/od/multimedia/a/mime-types-by-content-type.htm) to get the detail List of MIME Types by Content Type.
Here is some main types

```
application/mac-binhex40    hqx
application/msword          doc
application/msword          dot
application/octet-stream    *
application/octet-stream    bin
application/octet-stream    class
application/octet-stream    dms
application/octet-stream    exe
```

And the thing which you are looking for is already used by you `application/octet-stream for *`

Comment: i was trying to download jsp page, but my console did not give any response.But i've figured it out why.. Thanks for the feedback.